# Adding to Front of Doubly Linked List, Why is my List Incorrect and Getting Printed out Backwards?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Creating a doubly linked list (has head and tail pointers). I've made functions for adding to the list and printing out. The output I'm getting shows a problem but after staring at it for some time,  I have no idea what's going on. It seems, each time I add a new node to the front, the data from the last node I added gets overwritten with what's in the new one, and the list gets printed out backwards.

Here's what I have:

```
class node
{
    public:
        node *prev = nullptr;
        node *next = nullptr;
        int val;
        node(int value);
};
```

```
class linkedList
{
    private:
        node *head = nullptr;
        node *tail = nullptr;


    public:
        linkedList();
        void addToFront();
        void addToBack();
        void deleteFront();
        void deleteBack();
        void moonwalkThroughList();
        void printList();
        void inputVal(int &integerStore);
};
```

```
void linkedList::addToFront()
{
    int dataForFront = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the value for the node you want to go in the front: " << endl;

    inputVal(dataForFront); //Just validates dataForFront is a positive integer

    node *tempPTR = new node(dataForFront);

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = tempPTR;
        tail = tempPTR;
        cout << "Head was null." << endl;
        cout << "val in head is now: " << head->val << endl;
    }
    else if (head != nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Head is not null" << endl;
        cout << "Adding new node to the front" << endl;
        tempPTR->next = head;
        head->prev = tempPTR;
        head = tempPTR;
    }
}
```

```
void linkedList::printList()
{
    node *tempPTR = nullptr;

    tempPTR = head;

    cout << "The list of nodes is: ";

    cout << tempPTR->val << " ";

    while (tempPTR->next != nullptr)
    {
        cout << tempPTR->val << " ";
        tempPTR = tempPTR->next;

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

}
```

All I'm doing in main is:

```
linkedList firstList;

firstList.addToFront();
firstList.printList();
```

Output is:

> Hello, welcome to the menu! Please select an option.
>   1. Add a new node to the head.
>   2. Add a new node to the tail.
>   3. Delete the first node in the list.
>   4. Delete the last node in the list.
>   5. Traverse the list reversely.
>   6. Traverse the list.
>
> Please enter here:  1  Please enter the value for the node you want to
>   go in the front:  Please enter here:  2  Head was null.  val in head
>   is now: 2 The list of nodes is: 2
>
> Hello, welcome to the menu! Please select an option.
>   1. Add a new node to the head.
>   2. Add a new node to the tail.
>   3. Delete the first node in the list.
>   4. Delete the last node in the list.
>   5. Traverse the list reversely.
>   6. Traverse the list.
>
> Please enter here:  1  Please enter the value for the node you want to
>   go in the front:  Please enter here:  4  Head is not null  Adding new
>   node to the front  The list of nodes is: 4 4
>
> Hello, welcome to the menu! Please select an option.
>   1. Add a new node to the head.
>   2. Add a new node to the tail.
>   3. Delete the first node in the list.
>   4. Delete the last node in the list.
>   5. Traverse the list reversely.
>   6. Traverse the list.
>
> Please enter here:  1  Please enter the value for the node you want to
>   go in the front:  Please enter here:  6  Head is not null  Adding new
>   node to the front  The list of nodes is: 6 6 4

Comment: When creating a [mcve] to show us it often helps if you create a simple `main` function with hard-coded values for input. It's hard in your case since you ask for input in the `addToFront` function instead of passing the value as argument to the function (which is really recommended).

Comment: As for what I think your problem is, try to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your `printList` function. Will it ever print the *last* node in the list (i.e. will it ever print the node where `tempPTR->next == nullptr`)?

Comment: Draw out on paper what is happening in your print function... and talk to the duck -- it helps.

Comment: If you're adding to the front of your list with each input, then enumerating the list from front to back, naturally the last thing you input will be the *first* thing printed, then the next-to-last, etc. Iow, pushing on the front then printing front-to-back effectively shows you a *stack*. I don't see the problem there. Yeah, I would do quite a bit different in the code, but that's not really related to your query. I would *certainly* remove the IO from your list management, and instead just have the list do "list things", and having IO gather data, then call the list operations.

Comment: @WhozCraig Now that you mention that, it is doing what it should be doing as far as the order goes. Guess I was just looking at it too long. The problem that remains now is the last node that gets put in overwrites the one before it.  Input was 2 4 6. First 2 got put in, then 4 got put in and turned the 2 into a 4. Then 6 got put in and turned the 4 that came before it into a 6.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It appears to be doing exactly that, so I'd say yes. It's erasing the value of the node that came before the last one that was printed. Input was 2 4 6. First 2 got put in, then 4 got put in and turned the 2 into a 4, leaving the list with 4 4.. Then 6 got put in and turned the 4 that came before it into a 6, leaving the list as 6 6 4

Comment: Your `printList` function also have another bug (besides not printing the last node): It prints the first node *twice*. Two bugs that probably explains the behavior you see. You might want to step through the function statement by statement in a debugger to see these two bugs happening.